# Nginx: try_files outside location

Tags: configuration, nginx

I'm configuring a pretty standard webserver using nginx. The server is working as expected, however, there is a small configuration detail I would like to understand.

My current configuration is:

```
index index.html index.htm index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

With this configuration, if I access to: http://myweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/cropped-bitmap11.png/lol.php I get a 404 as expected.

However, with this configuration:

```
try_files $uri =404;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

I get a blank page with "Access denied".

Why is the result different?

Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are probably under the impression that `try_files` on server level must work for every request. Not at all. Quite the contrary, it works only for requests that match no `location` blocks.

Answer (score 3):

**short anwser:** as of php5.3.9, php-fpm does not allow extensions other than .php and .php5 because of the default value for `security.limit_extensions` and your request as been made to an existent .png file.

**long answer:** this is nothing to do with try_files being inside or outside of a location block. let's break and explain:

request is: http://myweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/cropped-bitmap11.png/lol.php

**on your first configuration**

- it matches the `location ~ .php$ { ... }` block because the request ends with `.php`.
- the  `try_files $uri =404;` directive inside `.php$` location causes nginx return 404 as there is no file named $uri (=/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/cropped-bitmap11.png/lol.php)
- the `location / { ... }` block never matches. it is only matched if no other location blocks are matched. (see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location)

**on your second configuration**

- again, as the request ends with `.php`, it matches the `.php$` location block.
- there is no check for a file existence inside the location block, the request is directly passed to the fastcgi process.
- fastcgi process finds the `/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/cropped-bitmap11.png` (appearently, it exists) and denies to run the request, because of the .png extension. (see the short answer)

i don't know if it is a bug or a "by design" thing but, contrary to "root" directive, a try_files directive outside the location blocks does not inherited inside the location block. (somebody may correct this if it is wrong)

Comment: `a try_files directive outside the location blocks does not inherited inside the location block` I think this is the key point. If this is right, all makes sense